# Reducing Bar Width in Webi Reports

Tags: business-intelligence, business-objects

Is there any way to reduce the bar width in a Column Chart?

Please guide me if this is possible.

Thanks

Niki

Answer (score 0):

If you go to "Format" - Chart, then click on the Series tab, you can adjust the Gap width for Bar charts. Technically this adjusts the gap between the bars, but has the effect of adjusting the width of the bars as well.

Hope this works for you

Comment: Unfortunately changes cannot be seen.